# How to add a UIWebView to UIActionSheet?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make a `UIActionSheet` that contains a `UIWebView` using Objective-c.

I couldn't find an answer for this question:  most of the answers I found were using normal alerts to the `UIWebView`.

How can I make a `UIWebView` appear in a `UIActionSheet`?

Answer (score 0):

UIActionSheet is not designed to display HTML content. Apple documentation:

> use the UIActionSheet class to present the user with a set of alternatives for how to proceed with a given task. You can also use action sheets to prompt the user to confirm a potentially dangerous action. The action sheet contains an optional title and one or more buttons, each of which corresponds to an action to take.
>
> UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the `UIActionSheet` API, you can create your own and present it modally with presentViewController:animated:completion:.

The answer to your question is use a custom `UIView` or a container viewController. 
PS: `UIActionSheet` is deprecated in iOS 8. To create and manage action sheets in iOS 8 and later, instead use `UIAlertController`

Comment: Thanks for answering but can i make a custom UIView that looks like the ActionSheet  all i want is to implement the UIWebView in it and when the user click anywhere in the screen it disapear can it do that and  if how ?